# What graphical program to use for matrix/matrices?

Tags: matrices

I have seen many representations of matrices but I have never found suitable program for it how to make it really readable and add some graphics there ... What program do you choose when you want to present your matrices equations in public?

Still do not know what is the question about? See site like this:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-introduction.html - see the graphical use to present matrices? I there any editor which can do that and for example visible transfom it to PDF etc? I would like it for educational purposes so something where I can add some comments etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want something beyond just using Latex?

Comment: Yes - even something like this http://assets.devx.com/articlefigs/40223AB-BA1.GIF or this http://www.aulafacil.com/matematicas-matrices-determinantes/curso/matricesydeterminantes040.jpg people have to do it somewhere, my question is where to make it like this very easy in what software.

Comment: Hmm, in my opinion you get better looking results using Latex.  I'm not sure about how to use color though.

Comment: I dont like it really and do not funtion in my win 8 64bit quite well ...